# Generics vs Class<?>

Tags: java, jython

Is it possible to get implement the class from the generic for type casting 
for example this fail for me buildingObject.**tojava**(S) in below example

```
public abstract class AbstractPythonService implements FactoryBean<IHelloService> {

    public IHelloService getObject() {

        //Here is the actual code that interprets our python file.
        PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
        interpreter.execfile("src/main/python/HelloServicePython.py");
        PyObject buildingObject = interpreter.get("HelloServicePython").__call__();


        //Cast the created object to our Java interface
        return (IHelloService) buildingObject.__tojava__(IHelloService.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return IHelloService.class;
    }
}
```

I want something like this

```
public abstract class AbstractPythonService<S> implements FactoryBean<S> {

    public S getObject() {

        //Here is the actual code that interprets our python file.
        PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
        interpreter.execfile("src/main/python/HelloServicePython.py");
        PyObject buildingObject = interpreter.get("HelloServicePython").__call__();


        //Cast the created object to our Java interface
        return (S) buildingObject.__tojava__(S.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return S.class;
    }
}
```

Comment: Class<?> is a parameterized class. As `?` is used, it can return class of any type. You mentioned that it fails for you, what is the error message?

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. It might also help if you give at least the signature of that interface method you are overriding and asking about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of type erasure you need a `Class<S>` object, some `Xyz.class`.

```
public abstract class AbstractPythonService<S> implements FactoryBean<S> {
    private final Class<S> type;

    protected AbstractPythonService(Class<S> type) {
        super(type); // Probably the factory would also need the type.
        this.type = type;
    }

    return type.cast(buildingObject.__tojava__(type)); // type.cast probably unneeded.

public Class<S> getObjectType() {
    return type;
}
```